# Push object on array when checkbox is checked and remove object when checkbox is unchecked in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new to angular 6.

I am trying to handle pushing and removing object from an array based on whether a checkbox is checked or not.
So i am success to push object to array but How can I remove the same object from array when I uncheck the checkbox ?
I also use formArray.

HTML Code Here

```
<form [formGroup]="editCategoryForm" > 
          <div class="form-group">
                  <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput placeholder="Name"  formControlName="name" >
                  </mat-form-field>
              </div>
          <div formArrayName="categoryArray" >  
            <fieldset *ngFor="let address of editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray['controls']; let i = index" >
              <div [formGroupName]="i" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput placeholder="Label" formControlName ="label"  required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                   <br/>
                        <div class="check-box" *ngFor="let data of measurementData">
                              <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(i,data._id,data.name, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="inputChecked(i,data)" > {{data.name}}
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" *ngIf="editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray['controls'].length > 1" title="Remove Fields" (click)="removeLair(i)">x</button>     
                        </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset> 
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="addNew()">Add Measurement</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <button style="float: right;margin: 29px;"  mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="submitdata()">Submit</button>          
            </div>  
            </div>
        </form>
```

TS Code Here

```
onChange(index: number, _id: string, name: string, isChecked: boolean) {

    if (isChecked) {
      this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.push({ id: _id, name: name });
    } else {
      this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.pop({ id: _id, name: name });
    }
  }
```

Here is a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-neny5v?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts).This Example is not working properly its remove object from last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

HTML : Instead of passing each field, pass the whole object

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(i,data, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="inputChecked(i,data)" >
```

TS : Use `splice()` instead of `pop()`

```
onChange(index: number, data:{_id:string,name:string}, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.push(data);
    } else {
      this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.splice(this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.indexOf(data),1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You had used pop method which will always remove last element from your array. If you want to remove specific element from your array then use splice method. Please try this

```
onChange(index: number, _id: string, name: string, isChecked: boolean) {

    if (isChecked) {
      this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.push({ id: _id, name: name });
    } else {
      this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in place of `pop` you can try `filter` because pop will always remove element from last but by filter we can filter according to condition.

```
 onChange(index: number, _id: string, name: string, isChecked: boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.push({ id: _id, name: name });
        } else {
    //this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.pop({ id: _id, name: name });
    this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements=this.editCategoryForm.controls.categoryArray.value[index].measurements.filter(item=>_id!==item.id);
        }
      }
```

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zb2zwf)